# TWIG: is defined and is not null

Tags: symfony, twig

quick question
I have a var and I want to check if it is defined (to avoid have a bug in the render) and if it is not null (to display something with a Else if null)

`{% if var  is not null %}` works

`{% if var  is defined %}` works

`{% if var  is not null and is defined %}` does not work
any idea of the correct syntax?

**EDIT** the workaround will be:

```
{% if var is defined %}
    {% if var is not null %}
        {{ var }}
    {% else %}
        blabla
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

That a lot of code for something simple... ideas how to merge the two IF?

Comment: try checking `defined` before `is not null`

Comment: nope {% if var  is defined and is not null %} is not working either

Comment: `is not null` mean that `var` exist.

Comment: you are forgetting to reference `var` again in the second statement `{% if var is defined and var is not null %}`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Wrong**

```
{% if var is not null and var is defined %}
```

This does not work because a variable which is null in twig is defined, but if you check for null first and it is not defined it will throw an error.

**Correct**

```
{% if var is defined and var is not null %}
```

This will work because we check if it is defined first and will abord when not. Only if the variable is defined we check if it is null.

Comment: For completion, it could be worth mentioning that you **must** reference `var` in each statement, which you did in your answer but the OP wasn't doing in his code (he wrote `{% if var is not null and is defined %}`)

Answer (score 8):

I have always used the ?? operator to provide a 'default' value when I know a variable might not be defined. So `{% if (var is defined and var is not null) %}` is equivalent to:

```
{% if (var ?? null) is not null %}
```

If you just want to check whether a value that might not be defined is truthy you can do this:

```
{% if (var ?? null) %}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare the var in each check so `{% if var is defined and var is not null %}`.

Answer (score 3):

Just like any other programming language, you will still need to make a reference to the variable for each check you make.

```
{% if var is defined and not null %}
```

This won't work because after checking is defined twig doesn't know what you're attempting to check for a null on. The solution:

```
{% if (var is defined) and (var is not null) %}
... code
{% endif}
```

The parenthesis are not necessarily required. It's more of a preference for readability. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one that is a bit shorter. It's not 100% equal to the null test but it suit my usage.

```
{% if var is defined and var %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the shortest syntax for what you are trying to check

```
{% if var ?? false %}
```

Comment: Looks smart, but does not convey the intention clearly. This reduces maintainability.